# Check whether a value exists in an HBase table

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I've got an HBase table with data that looks like:

```
key1 c:hasErrors false
key2 c:hasErrors true
key3 c:hasErrors false
```

I want to check whether the column qualifier `hasErrors` has a value `true` anywhere in the table.

Obviously I can do a scan:

```
Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(colFam, colQual);
Filter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(colFam, colQual, CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
                new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("true")));
scan.setFilter(filter);
ResultScanner results = table.scan(scan, auditTableName);
```

but that's undesirable because any matching rows will be pulled back to my app, and I have to check whether `results.next() != false`.

Is there a way to just have a boolean returned that tells me whether or not the value is present in at least one row?

Comment: I don’t any other way and scans should be avoided for performances reasons. Consider having another HBase table to track counts of hasErrors, and populate it together with the initial table.

Comment: @Harold thanks, I haven't found another way either. Luckily it's not a huge issue (I'm scanning with a row key prefix, and the scan isn't run particularly often).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.filter.SingleColumnValueFilter

/**
 * Set whether entire row should be filtered if column is not found.
 * 
 * If true, the entire row will be skipped if the column is not found.
 * 
 * If false, the row will pass if the column is not found.  This is default.
 * @param filterIfMissing flag
 */
public void setFilterIfMissing(boolean filterIfMissing) {
  this.filterIfMissing = filterIfMissing;
}
```

According to docs, it will not return rows that did not match.

P.S. If you use Get, you have `setCheckExistenceOnly` method for the similar purpose